# how to convert facebook response date to unix time stamp

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, datetime, simpledateformat

I am able to get all user feed to facebook graph api in my android app. Following is date string from `updated_time` key :

```
  2014-12-14T18:23:17+0000
```

First  I wasn't able to find  format for this string. From google I only come to know, this is might be `RFC 2822 date format`.

I want to convert this date string to unix time stamp to fetch new user feeds. How can I convert this string to unix time stamp?

If I try to parse this string using following formate I'm getting null date:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format pattern is wrong.

```
String timeStamp = "2014-12-14T18:23:17+0000";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println("Unix timestamp: " + dateFormat.parse(timeStamp).getTime());
```

Answer (score 2):

It is advised to strip the +0000 from the date as this is the timezone information. Then handling the timezone separately i.e. as an integer you can either add or subtract it from the time in millis by multiplying the timezone stripped and converting it to milliseconds.

```
public static long getDateInMillis(String srcDate) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat desiredFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

        long dateInMillis = 0;
        try {
            Date date = desiredFormat.parse(srcDate);
            dateInMillis = date.getTime();
            return dateInMillis;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}
```